# Create Salesforce CICD Pipeline Using Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, pipeline

A client has an **Azure DevOps** subscription and they're looking to use it for **automated builds and releases** with their **Salesforce** app they're using. The previous dev team was only using Azure Repos as their code repository and the client was using Boards for ticket tracking. I believe the previous team used **Salesforce DX/CLI** to perform deployments using **VS Code** so no pipelines exist and they'd have to be created from scratch.

I've come across a few articles (not many) with instructions to set up the build and release pipelines in Azure DevOps but my concern is whether or not its only possible with **Scratch Org or Sandbox environments**? I have no background with Salesforce and limited experience creating build and release pipelines.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Somebody can probably help you here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com. Or maybe even on https://stackoverflow.com. But this doesn't really seem the right place for such a question.

Comment: Noted, thank you for the suggestion